# Donor access to edit recurring donations

Tags: iats, user-dashboard

WP 4.8
Civi 4.7.21
iATS Payments 1.6.0

Our donors have very limited ability to edit recurring donations. Ie. if their card expires they cannot update the expiry date. Or if the card number is changed, they cannot update to a new card number.

As admin, I can see an update card info but the donor cannot.

I have looked at ACL but have not seen anything there that looks like would give/restrict that ability.

Is there something I am missing in the ACL or is this an iATS Payments setting?

Comment: can you specify if your users have access to the dashboard and if so confirm that Contributions and Recurrings are showing there? What I see on a system i checked was that the user has access to an Edit button but also to "change billing details' via a 'more' link

Comment: I as an administrator have access to the More with Change Billing. The donors do have a dashboard. When they log in to see it, they can see View and Edit. If they click View, they get a message that they do not have permission to access this. They cannot see the More link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - check the iATS settings (1.6.x version) - this was work merged here:
https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/pull/175

and documented (a bit): https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/wiki/Update-Recurring-Billing

I've not used it myself yet for any of our projects; So be careful and give it a good test drive;

Comment: This worked! I have not tested an actual edit of card info. But I did log in as a donor rather than admin and I was able to able to get to the form to update the card info. Thanks Karin for all your work on the iATS Payment integration.

Comment: Excellent - this work was by Konadave!

Answer (score 0):

A friend asked for the links that are used in case they can be put in to receipt template. this is what i dug out of contact dashboard

civicrm/contribute/updatebilling?reset=1&crid=XXXX&cid=YYYY

civicrm/contribute/updaterecur?reset=1&action=update&crid=XXXX&cid=YYYY

civicrm/contribute/unsubscribe?reset=1&crid=XXXX&cid=YYYY

not sure how useful this is but wanted to paste it somewhere other than skype ;-)

--

Evan's findings.

WordPress 4.7.3 | CiviCRM 4.7.22 | iATS Payments 1.6.0

Providing a link to update / cancel a recurring donation should be included in the receipt, and it is. Sort of. From the iATS Payments 1.6.0 release notes:

> *"Cancel/modify URL receipt links are wrong. This affects recurring contributions. You can manually edit the message template to fix this."*

https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/blob/master/release-notes/1.6.0.md
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20401

While debugging using the Send Receipts workflow from a contribution search, it was discovered the URLs in these links are built correctly. When sent automatically from the creation of a contribution, the links point to iATS website, when sent from a contribution search they're. As such, I was able to get the URL scheme of how it should be built, see below.

civicrm/contribute/unsubscribe&reset=1&coid={contribution.contribution_id}&cs={contact.checksum}

civicrm/contribute/updatebilling&reset=1&coid={contribution.contribution_id}&cs={contact.checksum}

civicrm/contribute/updaterecur&reset=1&coid={contribution.contribution_id}&cs={contact.checksum}

Comment: I am the friend that asked for this, and I am editing Pete's answer above to include my findings. And I'm editing instead of commenting because the formatting is better.